# Django geoposition the issue of mapping field- GeopositionField() of model

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have used django -geoposition to mapping the location of my model. Everything ok then I try add model to the base using admin, I can see map in the admin . But then I try to render location field to template, I see a grey square in my page where a map must be. And I don't know why I have this problem. I am using django 1.6

I use the code wich I have copied from documentation in my template:

```
  {% extends "main.html" %}

  {% block content %}
{{ instance.position.latitude }}
{{ instance.position.longitude }}
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function addMarker(lat, lng, title) {
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: position,
map: map,
title: title
});
bounds.extend(position);
}
addMarker({{ instance.position.latitude }}, {{ instance.position.longitude }}, "{{ instance.adress }}");
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your settings.py. Change laguage code to en-US in example and it should work

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
{% load l10n %}
{% localize off %}
{{ instance.position.latitude }},
{{ instance.position.longitude }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

or only:

```
{{ instance.position }}
```

this includes latitude & longitude